# the screen is locked when I open settings in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lock-screen

Hi I am new in Linux and I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 until now when I open the setting it works fine now it looks the screen also my keyboard and the mouse are connected with USB and in the lock screen they work very slow
I did not install anything on my machine I am using gnome 
what do I need to do? and why this happening? thanks